# Bootstrap carousel not initiating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot get Bootstrap Carousel to start, um, carousel-ing.  Below is all the code that is involved with what I'm trying to do.  When it renders in the browser, all I see are two images, one above the other, and a less-than and greater-than beneath them.  It's just rendering the DIVs as defined by the HTML as opposed to rendering in a Carousel.  I verified that the jQuery.ready function is being called, and is calling the code to initialize the carousel.  I also tried this on multiple browsers - IE9, Chrome, and Firefox.  I'm running out of ideas.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link type="text/css" href="styles/carousel.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#carousel').carousel();
        });

    </script>

    <div id="carousel" class="carousel">

      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
           <img src="images/APM_icon_big.png" alt="Some Alt Text" />
           <div class="carousel-caption">
             Some caption
           </div>
         </div>

        <div class="item">
           <img src="images/appdev_icon_big.png" alt="Some Alt Text" />
           <div class="carousel-caption">
             Some caption
           </div>
         </div>

        …

      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
       <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure about this?
`href="#carousel"`

Comment: Do you get any carousel behaviour when you click on the arrows? Try adding a class of "slide" to the div that has a class of carousel. You might be missing some CSS. Is the carousel.css that you are including the one from bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing a `rel="stylesheet"` in my `LINK` tag!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working just fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/MVGKP/)

Be sure to include the styles defined by bootstrap for the carousel : the css included in the fiddle comes from the [twitter-bootstrap custom download page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html) selecting only the *JS components* > *Carousel*.

It might not hurt to put your `<script>` inside the `<head>` or at the end of your page.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was missing a rel="stylesheet" in my LINK tag.  Thanks for your help!